# What is the most reliable way to import self-updating financial data into R currently?

Tags: r, finance

The broad question of finding free financial data has been tackled extensively (http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online), however, all things R change like the wind. Many answers from that page date to 2012, and similar questions on this stack are outdated.

I'm looking primarily for end of day equity data, but bond yields or currency prices would be good too. Also, I'm not looking for just spreadsheets of historical data, but rather a package or API I can call on in a script. This way it will be part of a dynamic model going into the future.

Answer (score 1):

Stay away from Yahoo finance. They have unreliable corporate action adjustments.
Register for a free account at Quandl. Check out the [Quandl R API](https://www.quandl.com/tools/r).
They have high, low, open, close, and volume (HLOCV) data for around 3000 US stocks for free. Plenty of other stuff for free also.